# I think a question should be added to the chat server FAQ. Who do I propose it to?

Tags: support, chat

I think there's a question that needs to / should be be added to the FAQ page on the chat servers (chat.stachexchange.net, chat.stackexchange.com). Who's responsible for the content of that page, for me to proposition with the suggest addition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would almost certainly be the [community team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99338/295684). However, proposed changes to network features (including documentation) are generally published publicly, right here on MSE. Write up your suggestion and tag it [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request). Other users will be able to discuss and improve your suggestion; community feedback here shows the community team what network users think of proposed changes.